# Datamapper not accepting regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, sinatra, datamapper

I'm using a regex to validate a form field in my sinatra app that's being sent to my db using the data_mapper gem. The code I'm using for the field in my model is:

```
property :price, Float, :required => true, :format => /\$?\d{0,3}\.{1}\d{2}/
```

And it's being saved from the params:

```
b.price = params[:price]
```

I keep getting an invalid format error when I try to save, though. I checked my regex with [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/aSgVeCodW8) and it seems to be working correctly. Anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but here's what I'm currently doing as a solution:

```
property :price, Float, :required => true 
validates_format_of :price, :with => /\$?\d{0,3}(\.{1}\d{2})?/
```

And then:

```
c = params[:price]
c[0] == "$" ? b.price = c[1,7] : b.price = c
```

So if there's a "$" I'm just saving the number to b.price without it, otherwise the whole thing gets set to b.price. I feel like there should be a better way...